# Idiomatic way to kill -9 only if "graceful" way doesn't work?

Tags: signals, process-management

Is there a common way or existing utility to do the following?

- `kill` a process
- Give it a few seconds to shut down gracefully
- `kill -9` it if it hasn't stopped

Comment: [This SuperUser answer](http://superuser.com/a/223200) is useful but `pgrep` is not guaranteed to be available everywhere. Also it is `bash`-specific

Comment: Agree with 1_CR's comment and the linked answer. Pretty much the only way to do it is to poll and sleep. Problem is, it is impossible to look inside the program and know whether sending a SIGTERM, SIGINT, etc. is actually causing it to *try* and terminate. Nor can you ever set a timeout large enough to account for programs that may take 1 minute, 2 minutes, an hour, 10 quadrillion millennia, etc. to successfully/gracefully terminate in response to a graceful termination signal. SIGKILL is basically "I can't afford to wait any longer, so *just die*".

Comment: The only change I'd make to that script from SU: If you have a bit more patience than 1 second, you can increase the sleep value (in seconds) to give the process more time to gracefully exit. DBs are famous for taking several seconds to flush their cached stuff in RAM to disk...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually I try to keep things as simple as:

```
kill $pid; sleep 5; kill -9 $pid
```

Or you can search a process by its name if you like:

```
pkill $pattern; sleep 5; pkill -9 $pattern
```

This is handy when you are working in a terminal, but for scripting you may prefer a more sophisticated solution from another answer.

Comment: Cleverly simple - you don't bother checking whether it has stopped because `kill -9 $pid` will have no effect if it has. +1 :)

Comment: @Nathan Long Or it will kill an innocent process if that $pid got recycled in the meantime. :)

Comment: @PSkocik Ooooh, good point...

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your ~/.bashrc file. Use it like this `killany program_name`. It will try to kill any program with a matching name.

```
killany ()
{
    PS=$(ps aux)
    PIDS=$(echo "$PS" | \   
    awk -v proc="$1" '{ reg=proc; if(match($11$12$13$14,reg)) print $2 }')
    if [ -n "$PIDS" ]; then
        echo "killing pids '$PIDS'"
        kill $PIDS 2> /dev/null
        sleep 3
        kill -1 $PIDS 2> /dev/null
        sleep 2
        kill -9 $PIDS 2> /dev/null
    else
        echo "none to kill"
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## "Kill Me Softly"

I just ran across project with a couple of small shell scripts for this.

https://github.com/alanfranz/killmesoftly